# Get reference to pictures taken on mobile device for resizing and uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera

We have an offline web app written with js/jquery/HTML5 that uses local storage to store multiple MB of data in json format that gets edited when the app is in use. This data eventually gets uploaded to our server via ajax. It works very well on both iOS and Android devices. We now want to allow users to repeatedly select an item in their data and take a picture to later be associated with that item. Pictures would be uploaded to our server along with the data. Pictures would also be reduced to 50kb or less in size with a canvas element either at the time they're taken or when they're uploaded. For any given upload, they're may a hundred or more pictures.

We had planned to store a reference to pictures as they're taken to later use for uploading. We now know, in a browser, without using native app code or frameworks such as PhoneGap, that there's no way to store such a reference or path when pictures are stored in the iOS camera roll or Android gallery. We can get the picture's file name by using an input control, but that's of no use without a full path. Also, all image filenames on iOS devices are "image.jpg". We could access the pictures' image data using data URLs, but we can't reliably store it because there' not enough space in local storage for both our json-formatted data and potentially hundreds of data URLs.

**So the question is, is there a way using js/jquery/html5 (not PhoneGap or native app code) to take a picture, get a reference to it for later resizing with a canvas element and then uploading via ajax?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if is there a way to resize image in Client-side using canvas to reduce them to 50kb then yes, there is.

Here is the link : http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/05/28/resizing-images-with-javascript.html

Here is a [DEMO](http://clientside-resize.labs.liip.ch/)

And here is the [CODE](https://github.com/nicam/js-resize)

I have tested it and it is really good.

PD. I dont like how this CODE resize the image, i changed it using another algorithm, let me know if you want it

Now i am looking for a way to listen the event when the mobile devise use the camera to take a photo and upload them. Because they are automatically rotated to left 90 grades.